# getting different output when calling function draw directly? React Tetris

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `draw()` function which updates my `state.board`.
When i call it through `game()` function with `setTimeout`, I am getting expected output.
 But when I try to call it directly, output is different. 
It looks like in the second case everything works as it should up to `this.setState({ board: newBoard }` line. My `state.board` is not being updated. Can you please tell me why?

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            board: [
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            ],
            piece:
                [
                    [1, 0, 0],
                    [1, 0, 0],
                    [1, 1, 1]
                ],
        }
    }
    game = () => {
        this.gameID = setTimeout(this.draw, 10);
    }
    draw = () => this.state.piece.forEach((row, yPos) =>
        row.forEach((blockColor, xPos) => {
            if (blockColor !== 0) {
                const newBoard = this.state.board.map((row, y) => row.map((value, x) => {
                    if ((y === yPos && x === xPos && blockColor !== 0)) { return value = blockColor }
                    else { return value }
                }));
                this.setState({ board: newBoard }, console.log("newBoard ", newBoard, "   state.board ", this.state.board));
            }
        }))
render() {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className="game-area">
                <Board board={this.state.board} />

            </div>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.game}>Start</button>

            <button type="button" onClick={this.draw}>step</button>

        </Layout>
    )
}
}

export default App;
```

What I get by calling game() (expected)

```
0: (10) [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1: (10) [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2: (10) [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
6: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
7: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
8: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
9: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
10: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
11: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
12: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
13: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
14: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
15: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
16: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
18: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
19: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

What I get by calling draw() directly:

```
0: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
6: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
7: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
8: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
9: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
10: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
11: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
12: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
13: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
14: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
15: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
16: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
18: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
19: (10) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

My Board component

```
import React from 'react';
class Board extends React.Component{
  render(){
  return (
   <div>
     {this.props.board.map((row,y)=>
       row.map((value,x)=>{

         const style ={
          top: (y*40) , left: (x*40),
          backgroundColor: 'red'
         }
         if(value===0){style.backgroundColor = 'blue'}
         else if (value ===1){style.backgroundColor = 'green'}
         else if (value ===2){style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'}
         //console.log("row: "+row+"x: "+x+"y: "+y);
         return(<div className = "block" style = {style}></div>)
       })
     )}
   </div>
  );
}}
export default Board;
```

Layout.js

```
    import React from 'react';

import Aux from '../hoc/Aux';

const layout = (props) => (
    <Aux>
    <div>Toolbar, SidePanel</div>
    <main>
        {props.children}
    </main>
    </Aux>

);

export default layout;
```

Comment: Can you share your Layout and Board components?

Comment: @MattOestreich components added

Comment: It would be super helpful if you could supply a CodeSandbox or something... The source code inside the post is desired, but a CodeSandbox or something like it, makes it way easier for others to help... more likely to get a quick answer that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` may run asynchronously. This means that `this.state` may not immediately be updated after you call `this.setState`. Thus, referring to `this.state` after updating is dangerous, because you'll be referring once again to pre-updated data within each loop iteration. Also, `setState` provokes an update, and you don't want to kick off multiple updates in response to one event.

I'd recommend you only do *one* `setState` operation, something like this:

```
draw = () => {
  let newBoard = this.state.board;
  this.state.piece.forEach((row, yPos) => {
    row.forEach((blockColor, xPos) => {
      if (blockColor !== 0) {
        newBoard = newBoard.map((row, y) => row.map((value, x) => {
          if ((y === yPos && x === xPos && blockColor !== 0)) {
            return value = blockColor 
          } else { 
            return value 
          }
        }));
      }
    })
  });

  this.setState({
    board: newBoard
  }, () => { 
    console.log("newBoard ", newBoard, "   state.board ", this.state.board) 
  });
}
```